# Add class if element has class, remove if it doesn't

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class to an element when it has the "active" class (assigned by bootstrap nav functionality) and remove the class when it is removed by bootstrap

I thought something like this would work, but it doesn't

```
if ($(".tree-parent > .tab-pane").hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).addClass("d-flex");
}
else {
    $(this).removeClass("d-flex");
}
```

Edit: As suggested in some of the comments I received, the problem was in the fact that the script was run only on page load and not when the "active" class was actually added/removed.
Thanks

Comment: Assuming the class is on the `.tab-pane` element when you run that code, it should work fine.

Comment: maybe you need check class in this element? if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Hi, the code that you're posting looks right at least in theory, we may have to see more like the HTML or a similar full example so we can try to identify the issue

Comment: try `console.log($(".tree-parent > .tab-pane"))` and see if it returns an object ..

Comment: Well, by "isn't working" I mean the class is neither added nor removed when it should. I was suspecting some king of syntax error, if the syntax seems right to you, I guess I have to look for the problem elsewhere

Comment: The syntax is fine, but as I mentioned above, you need to ensure that you run this logic at the right time in the page lifecycle. It would help to see more of your JS and HTML code to understand what context you're working in, and to create an example of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This should do.

```
$(function ($) {
  const $el = $('.tree-parent > .tab-pane');

  var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if ($el.hasClass('active')) {
      $el.addClass('d-flex');
    } else {
      $el.removeClass('d-flex');
    }
  });

  mutationObserver.observe($el[0], {
    attributes: true
  });
});
```

Don't forget to check if the correct element got selected.

Comment: This logic is different, as the OP add the class on `this`, whereas you add it to the `.tab-pane`, and this also won't work in IE

Comment: There is no `data-attribute-changed` event

Comment: I have changed the code and tested also in codepen

https://codepen.io/subhasism/pen/zmompv